# Best way to replace left and right parenths in a Get request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, urlencode

For my `GET` request, my server is rejecting it with `status: 403`, `"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"`

My `GET` request object as is follows :

```js
"{"method":"GET","url":"api/myapi/GETstuff","params":{"from":"2017-06-02","to":"2017-06-02","myData":"DATA (AND SOME/MORE DATA)"}}"
```

The javascript code is:

```js
function getMyData(params){

   var url = 'myapi/getStuff';
   
   var req = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: url,
      params: params
   };
   
   $http(req)     // details omitted for brevity
    .success()
    .error();

}
```

I believe the problem is special characters send to the IIS server (such as parenths, and `/` char), which I need to encode the `params` array before the `GET` request is sent via the Angular `$http()` service.

In order to encode the left/right parenths, and the `/` char, I'm trying:

```
request.params.myData = request.params.myData.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\//g, '%2F')
```

However, my server is still rejecting the request.

And I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to encode `params`? You seem to have a JSON object describing a request. What happens to that object?

Comment: sure you want to do a GET? Also, how does your URL look like after you have sent that sample request and what is your server expecting?

Comment: Please include the framework you're using to make requests. `request.parms` does not appear to be standard JavaScript code.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with it, but in your example data there is no '/' character, but there is a '\' character. Typo?

Comment: Angular 1.5.8 is the framework.

Comment: Why do you think the parentheses are the problem? That's not a rhetorical question; there must be something you've not mentioned that led you to that conclusion. Parentheses certainly don't have to be encoded in JSON, so unless the server specifically expects the properties of the `params` object to be URL-encoded, that's not the problem. If the API docs specifically say that that those properties should be URL-encoded (which is odd, since this is JSON, not a URL), then you should encode that value *before* serializing the object to JSON.

Comment: @JordanRunning I had thought that adding the [HttpGet] attribite to my c# Api method would solve it, but that was NOT the case at all. Our server (IIS 7.5) is rejecting any Get request which contains parenths. As of now the `/` and `-` chars are getting encoded and accepted by the server. The `(` and `)` chars are rejected.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're getting a Forbidden error. Sure you don't need to authenticate or pass a token?
2. Before getting too manual, I'd suggest trying JSON.stringify(obj) and as a second pass, encodeURIComponent(obj)
3. If you're posting a valid JSON object, you might want to consider POST instead of GET, if you have backend access.

Comment: we are definitely authenticated with the proper token. It's only when we select a dropdown value with any special character that it throws the `403 Forbidden` error. In our local dev envir, the error does NOT get thrown.

Comment: We have also tried to encode the parenths, etc., but the error is thrown regardless. We will have to consider a POST instead of GET.